# It is possible to match charcter with several condition?

Tags: regex, perl

My script is

```
foreach (<DATA>){
if( m/a[br\w][cq][ez][fx]g[hy]/g)
{
print "$&\n";
}
elsif( m/a[br][cq\w][ez][fx]g[hy]/g) 
{
print "$&\n";
}
elsif( m/a[br][cq][ez\w][fx]g[hy]/g){
print "$&\n";
}
elsif( m/a[br][cq][ez][fx\w]g[hy]/g){
print "$&\n";
}
elsif( m/a[br][cq][ez][fx]g[hy\w]/g){
print "$&\n";
}
}

__DATA__
abcefgh 
abqzxgh
arcefgy
abqzxgM
arMzfgy
arVRfgy
arVARgy
abcefgh
arcexgy
```

My script gave what i expect the output from my script

```
abcefgh
abqzxgh
arcefgy
abqzxgM
arMzfgy
abcefgh
arcexgy
```

Any possible to these if-else conditions script are shorted to the single regex line.

Comment: Don't get why such as `[br\w]`, `[cq\w]`, `[ez\w]`... as `\w` includes `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Possibly can [reduce it to something like this](https://regex101.com/r/mQ6pP3/2) (remove spaces or use with x-flag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `|` alteration to match multiple patterns. 
`/(?| (first)|(second) )/x`, puts any matched group into `$1`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $re = qr{
  (?|
    (a[br\w][cq][ez][fx]g[hy]) |
    (a[br][cq\w][ez][fx]g[hy]) |
    (a[br][cq][ez\w][fx]g[hy]) |
    (a[br][cq][ez][fx\w]g[hy]) |
    (a[br][cq][ez][fx]g[hy\w])
  )
}x;



while (<DATA>) {

  if (/$re/) {  print "$1\n"; }  
}
__DATA__
abcefgh 
abqzxgh
arcefgy
abqzxgM
arMzfgy
arVRfgy
arVARgy
abcefgh
arcexgy
```

output

```
abcefgh
abqzxgh
arcefgy
abqzxgM
arMzfgy
abcefgh
arcexgy
```

Comment: @cyxon27 not give the resul. But which is a nice idea

Comment: thank you.  Can you explain  What is the use of the `qr` `?|` and `x`?

Comment: @Khaja `/x` ignores whitespaces in regex, and check update for rest.